# Do I need to add products to Google Play Developer Console for Ionic In App Purchase

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am developing an application using ionic3 and the app is about selling books. I created  web application for the client so they can add book to the platform. Now I am considering In App Purchase as a means of payment on the mobile app but all the tutorial I have seen requires that I add the products to google developer console and Itunes. My question is Do I really need to add products to Google Play Developer Console for Ionic In App Purchase? Cos my Idea is just to request for the products available in the database and use inApp Purchase basically as a payment gateway

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup product offers in each platform.

The main reason is because Apple and Google performs purchase operation relying on the data stored on their side (app store connect or console), where price tier is fixed etc.

If the platforms would allow a developer server send arbitrary requests it would be super hard to manage for apple/google hence they prefer having products for sale defined on their end.

Client just mirrors data, but source of truth for offers is always Apple or Google side system.